# Java - Thread variable retaining previous value

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans, concurrency, timer

I've created a simple timer class which counts down from 20 to zero unless its timerStop variable is set to true, and updates a JTextFiled in an Array of GUIs after each second. Every time the timer is used a new GameTimer is created and passed to a new Thread.

PROBLEM: 
The first run of the timer executes as expected but subsequent instances will start by updating the GUI text field with the last value of the previous timer (the number it was stopped on) before counting down from 20 as it should.

I've tried resetting the variable back to 20 at the end of the code and printing out the value as a test, and the variable does indeed print "20", but still the GUI updates the previous stop time when the next instance is run.

I'm using Netbeans IDE 8.0.2

Really appreciate any advice and tips about my code, Thanks!

```
public class GameTimer implements Runnable 
{
  private volatile int secondsLeft;
  private MultiTextGUI[] guis;
  private boolean timerStop; 

  public GameTimer(MultiTextGUI[] MTguis)
  {
    secondsLeft = 20;
    guis = MTguis;
    timerStop = false;
  }     

  public void setTimerStop(boolean stop)
  {
    timerStop = stop;
  }        

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
      while (secondsLeft > 0 && !timerStop)
      {
        try
        {
         Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
         System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
        }    
        secondsLeft--;
        System.out.println(secondsLeft); //TEST
        for (MultiTextGUI gui: guis)
        {
          if (secondsLeft > 0)
          {
             if (gui != null)
             {    
               gui.updateTimer(secondsLeft);
             }
          }
          else
          {
             if (gui != null)
             {    
                gui.setTimerOn(false);
             }
          }
        }

      }
      secondsLeft = 20;
      System.out.println(secondsLeft); //TEST
  }
}
```

Main Thread:

```
GameTimer gt = new GameTimer(g);
Thread timerThread = new Thread(gt);
timerThread.start();

//code to show timer in gui
//code for countdownlatch

gt.setTimerStop(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swing components, you must update those components using the event-dispatch thread. Updating a component while inside a normal thread will cause all sorts of problems.

SwingUtilities.invokeLater is what you must use when updating a Swing component.

---

The following code makes certain that the statements contained within execute on the event dispatch thread. The reason this is critical is that you could corrupt the state of your swing UI (assuming that's what's being used here). Painting a GUI is single threaded, and if you jump in and update a component outside of that single thread (EDT), then the EDT might be in the middle of updating your component right when you are. Corruption being the least of the problems.

The really insidious part of this, is that updating components outside of the EDT will work 90% of the time. Then when you least expect it, something crazy happens. It might be that your problem here isn't related to this, but it is still important to update Swing within the EDT.

There are tutorials available.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{                        
    public void run ()
    {
        label.setText("New Value=" + x);
    }
});
```

Comment: so updateGUI() method needs to be run in the EDT? Could you show me a simple example of how to do this please.

Answer (score 0):

You are sleeping for one second prior to the updated value being set within the MultiTextGUI instances.  If the display is updating before this 1 second period, the thread running the timer would not have updated the displayed value causing the prior value to be displayed.  Not sure if you can set the value prior to the Thread.sleep(1000) call and preserve the behaviors you want.